# local storage expiring data

Tags: javascript, timestamp, local-storage

I am using localStorage to save conversations client-side to save space server-side in my db. In order to do it I use an object like this:

```
users = {
  478vh9k52k: {
    name: 'john',
    messages: []
  },
  42r66s58rs: {
    name: 'jack',
    messages: []
  }
};
```

I then use `users[id].messages.push(msgObj)` to push new messages inside the right user ID. Lastly I use `JSON.stringify` and then save the resulting string.

Problem with this is that slowly the string will grow, thus filling in the limits. It is not too much of a problem the length of the messages array, because I truncate it, but the existence of old users not being necessary anymore.

Question is simple: how can I delete the old users that are contained in the 'users' object? I was thinking to add a timestamp as a key inside the object and then accessing random users to check on them at every save.

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

why access them randomly? you could slice up your storage in days instead, with a

```
localStorage["chatLogs"] = {
  "13........0" : {
    bob: {},
    alice: {},
    christoffelson: {}
  }
  "13....86400" : {
    bob: {},
    alice: {},
    christoffelson: {}
  }
}
```

and then run through your object by its keys. If they're older than a day, delete them. Alternatively, you can have a look at using indexdb instead of localStorage if you're going to do a lot of querying/filtering.